# Fast way to loop over datagridview rows

Tags: c#, optimization, datagridview

I have a datagridview that contains a column with prices and more than 1000 rows 
i'd like apply a reduction to all those price example "-20%"

```
 product    price  
 product1    200
 product2    300
 product3    400
```

---

```
public class product
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
public List<product> GetListProduct()
{
       B_Entities dbCtx = new B_Entities();

        return dbCtx.B_PRODUCTS.Select(p => new Product{ ID= p.ID, Name= p.Name, Price= p.Price }).ToList();


}

dgvListeProd.DataSource = GetListProduct(); 

 Parallel.For(0, dgvListeProd.Rows.Count, index=>
            {
                  object priceValue = dgvListeProd.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value;

                if (priceValue != null)
                {
                    decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(priceValue);
                    decimal countedPrice = (price * pourcentage) / 100;
                     countedPrice = price - countedPrice;

                    dgvListeProd.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value =(double) countedPrice;

                }
            });
```

This generate an aggregate exception.
How to perform this task in fast way

Comment: It's not a looping,  but update problem. Are you using a data bound mode? If yes, what is the type of the data source?

Comment: the looping is the problem because when i tried with ordinary for loop i's work but take too much time, then i thought to parallelization of the process but didn't find the way to do this

Comment: No, it's not. If you just loop w/o the line `dgvListeProd.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value =(double) countedPrice;`, you should not have any problem at all - 1000 records are nothing for nowadays CPU. Please answer the question regarding data bound or unbound mode.

Comment: it's bound mode to a List<T>

Comment: Nice, now could you post the code of that *T*, i.e. the class that is contained in the list. And tell me if your grid view is using any sort of a column/row autosize features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to remember once forever (or at least for Windows Forms:-)) - UI is single threaded, you cannot "optimize" it using multi threading techniques, including parallel extensions.

The fastest way to perform update task is to update the **data**, and let the UI show what you did. Luckily you have a data source, so apply the operation on the data source (here you can use simple `for` or `Parallel.For`), and then just call `DataGridView.Refresh`.

Here is a full working sample similar to your case, which processes **1M** rows w/o any problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void ReducePrice(DataGridView productView, decimal percentage)
        {
            var factor = 1 - percentage / 100;
            var data = (List<Product>)productView.DataSource;
            Parallel.For(0, data.Count, index =>
            {
                var product = data[index];
                product.Price = (double)((decimal)product.Price * factor);
            });
            productView.Refresh();
        }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            dg.DataSource = GetProductList();
            var button = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Parent = form, Text = "Reduce Price by 20%" };
            button.Click += (sender, e) => ReducePrice(dg, 20);
            Application.Run(form);
        }
        static List<Product> GetProductList()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).Select(n => new Product { ID = n, Name = "Product#" + n, Price = random.Next(10, 1000) }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the for and Parallel.For take the same time, So should i use the simple for loop

Comment: @MediSoft Well, the sweet thing is that now you have a choice. So pick whatever you like :-)